# How can i avoid adding duplicates into array and only have one value at time for specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some `CalendarIcons` which looks like the picture in the link.

[CalendarIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5duG.png)

These icons have these id's:

- `autumn=2020-08-20`
- `autumn=2020-08-22`
- `spring=2020-04-20`
- `spring=2020-04-21`

I have created an array to hold dates: `const selectedDates = []` in my state.
When i select a date, I am able to push the `id` value into the `selectedDates` array.
When i select one icon i get the id: `autumn=2020-08-20` and pushed to my `selectedDates` array. But if i click the another icon with this id: `autumn=2020-08-22` its also pushed to the array.
But i only want one of the `autumn` value, and only one of the `spring` value in my array.
How can i fix so my array only contains one value of `autumn` or `spring` ?

This is my handleClicked method for the `CalendarIcons`:

```
    handleClicked(calendarIconId, rowLabelId) {

    // Should not add same value autumn, spring, etc. again, and only add one value specificed behind the =
    var dateArray = this.state.selectedDates.concat(calendarIconId);

    this.setState({
        calendarSelectedIconId: calendarIconId,
        rowTracker: rowLabelId,
        selectedDates: dateArray
    });
}
```

I hope the question is clear, give me feedback if the question is not clear. Thank for the help!

Comment: Have you looked at [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: You can use set for unique array see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `Set` instead of `Array`

[Great article about Set here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-set-vs-array-what-and-when-efc055655e1a)

`Set` will automatically make values uniques. You could have something like :

```js
// Declaration of the Set
const uniqueSet = new Set();

function handleClicked(calendarIconId) {
  // Add the new value inside of the Set
  uniqueSet.add(calendarIconId);
  
  // Turn the set into an array
  const array = Array.from(uniqueSet);

  console.log(array);
}

handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-20');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-20');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
```

---

EDIT : We only want to keep one value for each season :

```js
// Declaration of an object. We are going to use the key/value system
const library = {};

function handleClicked(calendarIconId) {
  // We "open" the value to extract the relevant informations
  const [
    key,
    value,
  ] = calendarIconId.split('=');

  // Add the new value inside of the object
  library[key] = value;
  
  // Turn the object into an array, we gotta rebuild the values
  const array = Object.keys(library).map(x => `${x}=${library[x]}`);

  console.log(array);
}

handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-20');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('autumn=2020-08-22');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-20');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
handleClicked('spring=2020-04-21');
```

Comment: But i only want one of the `autumn` date, not both. How i can replace `autumn=2020-08-20` with the new value `"autumn=2020-08-22"`. Cus i only want one of `autumn` date inside the array.

Comment: Oh alright I haven't understood that. Let me adapt my answer. *edit -> It's done

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if(!Array.includes(id)) {
  Array.push(id)
}
```